# htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

how do I rewrite web requests of type
http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=somenumber   where somenumber is an integer
TO
http://mydomain.com/directory

like http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=15 to http://mydomain.com/directory

Comment: it is actually the opposite buddy, you rewrite the rules to take directories and transform them into .php?id=15 an example would be, user request http://mydomain.com/fish and the module will rewrite it to http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?category=fish, to have the actual id you would do something like http://mydomain.com/15/fish that would go for http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=15

Comment: Can you help me with that then? rewrite the "directory" to "mypage.php?id=15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, well, assuming the comment on your question is what you in fact want, you would do something like:

Somewhere on apache's config:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

On your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/directory/$ /mypage.php?id=something [NE,PT]
```

This would make it so that when you open `http://mydomain.com/directory/` it would serve exactly the same content as `http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=something`.

Edit: fixed typo on RewriteEngine and fixed the regexp too... was distracted.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this one generated internal server error.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite on your apache config?

Something like `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Oh I see the problem now... editing answer :P RewriteEngine not Rewire hehe!

Comment: I could go for a "rewire" engine for apache!

Comment: when tested, removing the / preceding directory seems to work

   RewriteRule ^directory/$ /mypage.php?id=15 [NE,PT]

Comment: That makes sense. Since you're putting the RewriteRule in a .htaccess file the RerwiteBase (baseline for all rewritten URLs) is automatically set to the directory where the .htaccess is.
Generally I put my RewriteRules on the vhost definition and I keep the preceding / for readability instead of setting RewriteBase.